# Do the spatial spherical harmonics form a complete basis over ${\rm I\!R}^3$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spherical-harmonics

It is well-known that the spherical harmonics form a complete orthogonal basis over the unit sphere $S^2$. But what about the spatial spherical harmonics (with the additional $r^n$ part), do they form a complete basis over ${\rm I\!R}^3$?

If not, I have a follow-up question. Is it then possible to find a solution to the Laplace equation that cannot be represented by a series expansion of the spatial spherical harmonics?

Comment: Yes, they do. All you have to do is first consider the unit vector on $S^2$ and then scale up the result by $r$.

Comment: I guess for *real* spherical harmonics you get a complete orthonormal basis w.r.t. $L_{\mathbb R}^2(S^2)$, i.e. the square integrable real functions on the unit sphere. So what function space over $\mathbb R^3$ are you talking about? $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$?

Comment: @K.defaoite Sorry to dig up an old post, but does this mean any $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ can be represented as $\int \sum c_{\ell, m} r Y_{\ell, m} dr$ or something like that?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing with that integral sign. I think you should be summing, no?

Comment: @K.defaoite Sorry I did not see the notification for your comment and must have not received one, but thank you for responding. What I meant is that if we have some function $g(r, \theta, \varphi)$ then we may write it as $$g = \sum_{\ell}\sum_m f(r) Y_{\ell, m}$$ where we set $f(r) = \iint g Y_{\ell, m} d\theta d\varphi$. Is that right?

Comment: @CBBAM Yes that looks like it should work, but don't take my word for it. Try out some numerical examples and see if it is giving the correct results.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thank you. I found a similar formula in a textbook so I assume it is correct.